# JPA batch_size property does not work for native query

Tags: sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, bulk

I'm trying to make a bulk insert with a native query.

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends CrudRepository<Entity, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "INSERT INTO table_name(value) VALUES (:value)", nativeQuery = true)
    void insert(@Param("value") String value);
}
```

I've added batch_size property to the application.properties file

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size = 50
```

But in the logs, I see that every insert processed separately. Is it possible to apply batching to native query?

Comment: You are calling this native query multiple times ?

Comment: Yes, I'm calling it multiple times.

Comment: Are you using @Transactional ? Maybe it will not work this way, you can use `saveAll` method to bulk insert.

Comment: I believe `saveAll` is for entities, but I'm using a native query.

Comment: What JDBC driver do you use? What [generating identifier value](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators) strategy do you use for the entity `Entity` ?

Comment: Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server. version="7.4.1.jre8"
this how I generate id
`@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)`
Anyway, I don't understand how id could affect bulk insert feature(

Comment: @DzmitryAtkayey Can you try adding properties: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=50
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true

Comment: Maybe to attempt rephrasing the question: is Hibernate even expected to batch native queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the entities use `GenerationType.IDENTITY` identifier generator, hibernate will silently disable batch inserts/updates.

Please find the following link for the details:
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-batch-insert-update#id-generation-strategy